# What is an uber JAR file?

Tags: java, maven, packaging, uberjar, fatjar

I am reading Maven documentation and came across the name `uber-jar`.

What does an `uber-jar` mean and what are its features/advantages?

Comment: I have also occasionally seen it called a "onejar" or "one-jar".

Comment: "uber" anything - unless in German, a concept named by an illiterate fool.

Answer (score 509, accepted):

`Über` is the German word for `above` or `over` (it's actually cognate with the English `over`).

Hence, in this context, an uber-jar is an "over-jar", one level up from a simple JAR <sup>(a)</sup>, defined as one that contains both your package *and* all its dependencies in one single JAR file. The name can be thought to come from the same stable as ultrageek, superman, hyperspace, and metadata, which all have similar meanings of "beyond the normal".

The advantage is that you can distribute your uber-jar and not care at all whether or not dependencies are installed at the destination, as your uber-jar actually *has* no dependencies.

All the dependencies of your own stuff within the uber-jar are *also* within that uber-jar. As are all dependencies of those dependencies. And so on.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I probably *shouldn't* have to explain what a JAR is to a Java developer but I'll include it for completeness. It's a Java archive, basically a single file that typically contains a number of Java class files along with associated metadata and resources.

Comment: Strange...  I am a german and of course know the word "über" and the meaning. But why is it used here in the Maven context? This case it means that one or more things are gathered together and is accessbile via the generated jar.  Unfortunateley this hint didn't sovle my maven issue ;-)

Comment: BTW, `über` and `over` are the result of a systematic vocal shift in Old Germanic which can also be observed in these word pairs: `geben/give`, `leben/live`, `haben/have`, `heben/heave` and many more.

Comment: Very smart description: Example [link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Comment: Given how much grief I've gotten about trying to *educate* people, I've decided to just remove the stuff that some keep complaining about. I still define uber in the context of the German language but the (somewhat verbose) history lesson is now gone :-)

Comment: Me: Reads "history lesson". Me: Opens revision history to read it. :-)

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação!

Answer (score 123):

From [imagej.net Uber-JAR description](https://imagej.net/develop/uber-jars):

> An **uber JAR** file is also known as **fat JAR**, i.e., a **JAR file
> with dependencies.**
>
> There are three common methods for constructing an uber JAR file:
>
> 1. **Unshaded:** Unpack all JAR files, and then repack them into a single JAR file. It works with Java's default class loader. Tools
>    [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)
> 2. **Shaded:** Same as unshaded, but rename (i.e., "shade") all **packages** of all dependencies. It works with Java's default class loader. It avoids some (not all) dependency version clashes. Tools
>    [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)
> 3. **JAR files of JAR files:** The final JAR file contains the other JAR files embedded within. It avoids dependency version clashes. All
>    resource files are preserved. Tools: [Eclipse JAR File Exporter](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-jar.htm)

Answer (score 64):

[Paxdiablo's definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar-file/11947093#11947093) is really good.

In addition, please consider delivering an uber-jar is sometimes quite useful, if you really want to distribute a software and don't want customer to download dependencies by themselves. As a drawback, if their own policy don't allow usage of some library, or if they have to bind some extra-components (slf4j, system compliant libraries, architecture specialize libraries, ...) this will probably increase difficulties for them.

You can perform that:

- basically with [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)
- a bit more further with [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

A cleaner solution is to provide their library separately; maven-shade-plugin has a preconfigured descriptor for that. This is not more complicated to do (with [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) and its plugin).

Finally, a really good solution is to use an [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) Bundle. There are plenty of good tutorials on that :)

For further configuration, please read those topics:

- *[Should you provide dependent libraries in client jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746336/should-you-provide-dependent-libraries-in-client-jar)*
- *[Best practices in building and deploying Clojure applications: good tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391711/best-practices-in-building-and-deploying-clojure-applications-good-tutorials)*

Answer (score 22):

### The different names are just ways of packaging Java applications.

**Skinny** – Contains *only* the bits you literally type into your code editor, and *nothing* else.

**Thin** – Contains all of the above *plus* the application’s direct dependencies of your applications (database drivers, utility libraries, etc.).

**Hollow** – The inverse of thin. It contains only the bits needed to run your application, but does *not* contain the application itself. Basically a pre-packaged “app server” to which you can later deploy your application, in the same style as traditional Java EE application servers, but with important differences.

**Fat/Uber** – Contains the bit you literally write yourself **plus** the direct dependencies of your application **plus** the bits needed to run your application “on its own”.

Source: [Article from Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/the-skinny-on-fat-thin-hollow-and-uber)

[image: Visual representation of JAR types]

Reposted from: *[What is a fat JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar/57592130#57592130)*

Comment: 'PLUS the bits needed to run your app “on its own”' 
Does that mean that I don't even need Java/JVM installed on the PC?

Comment: @MySurmise You still need to have Java/JVM/JRE installed.

Answer (score 4):

A self-contained, executable Java archive. In the case of WildFly Swarm uberjars, it is a single .jar file containing your application, the portions of WildFly required to support it, an internal Maven repository of dependencies, plus a shim to bootstrap it all. [see this](https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/getting-started/concepts.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to uber-JAR Documentation Approaches:
There are three common methods for constructing an uber-JAR:

**Unshaded** Unpack all JAR files, then repack them into a single JAR.
Tools: Maven Assembly Plugin, Classworlds Uberjar

**Shaded** Same as unshaded, but rename (i.e., "shade") all packages of all dependencies.
Tools: Maven Shade Plugin

**JAR of JARs** The final JAR file contains the other JAR files embedded within.
Tools: Eclipse JAR File Exporter, One-JAR.

Answer (score 1):

For Java Developers who use SpringBoot, **ÜBER/FAT JAR** is *normally* the final result of the `package phase` of maven (or `build task` if you use `gradle`).

Inside the Fat JAR one can find a `META-INF` directory inside which the `MANIFEST.MF` file lives with all the info regarding the Main class. More importantly, at the same level of `META-INF` directory you find the `BOOT-INF` directory inside which the directory `lib` lives and contains all the `.jar` files that are the dependencies of your application.

Comment: the same for gradle