# What are the differences between uberJar, fatJar and shadowJar in Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build

I'm trying to understand when should I use which. I understand that they all assemble all the dependent classes, but how are they different from each other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar

Answer (score 24):

The terms are sometimes used interchangeably, but usually refers to:

- **Fat jar** (also named **Uber jar**) - used to describe a jar that has all classes from dependent jars zipped directly inside it in the correct directory structure, and not in other jars. There is a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592130/411965).
- **Shaded jar** (or shaded classes) - usually refers to a process of changing classes bytecode to change packages names of the classes, and also modify were it is used in the jar. It is used to link classes to a specific version of other classes and avoid versions collisions. It can be created by [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). Shaded jar do not necessary contain all the dependencies needed.

The [gradle shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) can generate both fat jars and shaded jars, and same for the maven shaded plugin. I guess that is why people mix those terms.

Note: I have seen cases that refers to fat jar as a jar contains dependencies as a packed jars inside it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference whatsoever. These terms are all synonyms of each other.

The term "uber-jar" may be more commonly used in documentations (take the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) documentation for example) but "fat-jar" is also widely used.

Comment: not correct, unless you can explain why "terminology" leads to an extra plugin for gradle?

Comment: @MushyPeas All three commands come from a plugin. "Uber Jar", "Fat Jar" and "Shadow Jar" are all the same concept, and none of the commands are provided by gradle. The question did not ask about the difference between a "Shadow Jar" and "Jar".

Answer (score -1):

Uber Jar, Fat Jar and Shadow Jar are synonyms.

All three tasks do the same thing - you can choose the term you personally prefer the most.

Comment: shadowJar is an extra plugin and not a synonym, it creates different jar then the jar tasks of Gradle.