# How can I create jar that works in a similar manner to rt.jar using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Using Eclipse, when I write a 'hello world' test program the resulting executable jar is tiny despite rt.jar being on the build path. I would like to make a library-type jar that is added to the build path, but only contributes classes/code to the runnable jar if they are called/instantiated by the main application, as rt.jar seems to do.

Comment: Have you looked at what classpath does?

Comment: Just using the ordinary Export Jar (rather than Runnable Jar) gives you the small 'library' jar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Java works. The Java compiler and JAR are not a "all-in-one" packaging tool, they don't include every possible class into your exported JAR.

When you build a JAR with Eclipse, it only includes the classes and resources *from your project* that you specify (by default, it includes them all). On the other hand, `rt.jar` is part of the JRE distribution and is required for any Java program to run - it's part of the *runtime*. In other words, your little JAR would be useless without the machine it's running on having `rt.jar`.

For example, let's say in your project you write the following classes:

- `MyApp`
- `Person`
- `Account`

Each of those uses standard Java library classes like `String`, `Collection`, `Thread`, etc, which are all present in `rt.jar`

When you export/build your JAR, it will contain only `MyApp.class`, `Person.class`, and `Account.class`. It will *not* contain `String.class`, `Collection.class`, `Thread.class`, or any other classes from `rt.jar` (or from any other JAR that your project depends on).

Having said that, there are a few tools that try to build an "uber-JAR" (see [What is a fat JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19150811/639520)), but that's generally a special-need kind of thing, not how you would typically build JARs.