# SBT - unresolved dependencies in mapnik2geotools

Tags: scala, sbt

I try install [mapnik2geotools](https://github.com/dwins/mapnik2geotools). I've installed 0.11.2 sbt, java 7 and scala 2.9.1 which is required in build file, and when I run in I had following error:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\mapnik2geotools-master\mapnik2geotools-master>sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\mapnik2geotools-master\mapnik2geotools-master\project
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/mapnik2geotools-master/mapnik2geotools-master/project/}default-edb28e...
[info] Resolving com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.7.3 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.7.3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/0.7.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Admin\.ivy2/local/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/0.7.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/0.7.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.7.3/sbt-assembly-0.7.3.pom
[warn] ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried
[warn]   http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.7.3/sbt-assembly-0.7.3.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-core;2.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.9.1;6.0.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#main_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#actions_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#classfile_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#io_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#control_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#interface;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#logging_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#process_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#classpath_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#launcher-interface_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.9.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#incremental-compiler_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#collections_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#api_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#persist_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.9.0;0.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#compile_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#ivy_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.2.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.31 ...
[info] Resolving commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1 ...
[info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#completion_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;0.9.94 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#run_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#task-system_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#tasks_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#tracking_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#cache_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#testing_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#compiler-interface;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#precompiled-2_8_1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#precompiled-2_8_0;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#precompiled-2_9_0;0.11.2 ...
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/2.0.0/jars/sbteclipse-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.0.0!sbteclipse-plugin.jar (1724ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-core/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.2/2.0.0/jars/sbteclipse-core.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-core;2.0.0!sbteclipse-core.jar (1889ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-core_2.9.1/6.0.3/scalaz-core_2.9.1-6.0.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.9.1;6.0.3!scalaz-core_2.9.1.jar (1796ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.7.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.7.3 (sbtVersion=0.11.2, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn]
[error] {file:/C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/mapnik2geotools-master/mapnik2geotools-master/project/}default-edb28e/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.7.3: not found
```

I do update and compile with same error. Can you help me wo fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to install anything manually on your own. SBT should download and install everything as needed. I did not found any version of `com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly` for Scala Scala 2.9.1 [on the Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=%20artifact%20com.eed3si9n), unfortunately.

The versions you mention are quite old (Scala 2.9.1 was year 2011), so you might have a bit hard time searching for them.

As the purpose of `sbt-assembly` plugin is to build a [Fat Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar), you might be able to remove this plugin from a project and still be able to run it.

You might also upgrade to a newer version of `sbt-assembly`, but that will probably require you to use a newer SBT version as well, which might need some other changes in the build files.