# Unable to print results using XMLBean (XBProjector)

Tags: javascript, xml, selenium, xml-parsing, xmlbeans

I have the **Individual.XML** placed in the directory: **Files\InputApps**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<topmostSubform>
-<Header1>
<TextField2>**A123**</TextField2>
</Header1>
```

Just wanted to print out "**A123**" but I get this **error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlbeam/XBProjector
    at rb.form.submitter.Function_Library.printWeatherData(Function_Library.java:758)
    at rb.form.submitter.RB_base.main(RB_base.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlbeam.XBProjector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Please see my XMLBean code below:

```
@XBDocURL("resource://Files//InputApps//Individual.XML")

public interface XMLData {
    @XBRead("/topmostSubform/Header1/TextField2")    
    String getValue();   
}

protected void printData() throws IOException {
    // We let the projector fetch the data for us
    XMLData ValueData = new XBProjector().io().fromURLAnnotation(XMLData.class);

    // Print some values
    System.out.println("test " + ValueData.getValue());
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an external library ([enter link description here](https://xmlbeam.org)), but that lib is not in your class path during execution. You have to either include the library contents to your jar (creating a [fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar)), or provide a valid class path for the execution (java.exe -cp ...).

Comment: Thanks @cfx Yes, I was able to make it work by adding the libraries inside the Jar file. Can you also help me on my other problem? [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831634/how-to-map-two-similar-xml-element-using-xmlbeam)