# How to map two similar XML Element using XMLBeam?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmlbeans

This is the format of the XML so it is difficult for me to grab the 2nd instance:

```
<sec2_Ind>
 <SectC_EntyType>
  <TextField3>1</TextField3>
 </SectC_EntyType>
 <nameInfo>
  <subName>
   <fName>Name 1</fName>
  </subName>
 </nameInfo>
 <SectC_EntyType>
  <TextField3>2</TextField3>
 </SectC_EntyType>
 <nameInfo>
  <subName>
   <fName>Name 2</fName>
  </subName>
 </nameInfo>
<sec2_Ind>
```

From above, I am only able to get the 1st instance details (Name 1) as the elements does not have unique identifier except for `<TextField3>###</TextField3>`

What is the proper `@XBRead` format as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to read. Do you want the `SectC_EntyType` elements, or the `nameInfo` elements, or pairs of both of them?

Comment: Yes pairs of both of them. I am only able to get the first instance (TextField3:1 and fName:Name 1) and not the succeeding instance (TextField3:2 and fName:Name 2) using @XBRead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your answer I guess that you want a list of Strings:

```
 @XBRead("//(TextField3 | fName)")
 List<String> getNames();
```

Comment: Hi @Cfx, I think I am getting there. However, I tried `@XBRead("sec2_Ind//(TextField3 | fName)")` and `@XBRead("//(TextField3 | fName)")` and both gave me this error: **ERROR with File (Missing Fields):**

Comment: This does not sound like a Java error message. Can you poste the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @cfx I found the answer with the above script. The problem lies with me calling it and worked using the .get(sequence value) function