# Create fatjar using resources from another maven module in multimodule maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have maven multimodule project with the structure:

```
db
---> src
------> main
---------> resources

web
---> src
------> main
--------> resources
------------> dbs
----------------> lots of xml and csv files
```

I'd like to create `fatjar` which would contain all resources from `web`'s module `dbs` folder and the process is executed from `db` module

How can I achieve it?

What plugins to use?

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar)?

Comment: Create a parent which contains the db and the web as modules and based on that you can create a separate new module dist/fat whatever which creates the resulting file...