# Run java program classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I´m trying run a **java jar** with classpath argument like

I need run in this format:

```
java -cp "hibernateexample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" 
com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.hibernate.App
```

But i receive this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry
    at com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.hibernate.service.BookService.<init>(BookService.java:13)
    at com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.hibernate.App.main(App.java:11)
```

How do I run the **java jar** with **hibernate dependencies** without mistakes?

In eclipse it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the depended jars to your Java runtime.

```
java -cp "hibernateexample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;lib/*" com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.hibernate.App
```

You can also run your program in an IDE.

Comment: You may also consider packaging all dependencies into a single JAR: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar

Comment: no, as david said, either add the dependencies to the jar or you provide the `java` executable with the path to the dependent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your java program from any IDE like Eclipse or any another do not need to explicitly set environment variable CLASSPATH or PATH but if you try to run from terminal (in unix/linux/mac) or from command prompt ( in windows) you have to set your CLASSPATH or PATH as per requirement either temporarily or permanently. for more details you can visit: https://www.mysoftkey.com/java/path-and-classpath-in-java/