# Android : Program type already present: com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferencequeue

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Getting the following error during my gradle build :

*Program type already present: com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferencequeue*

I understand there to be some solutions on the site for similar such errors. But they don't work for me + they don't help me search the root cause of the error. Can someone please help with some pointers ??

App level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {

flavorDimensions "default"
compileSdkVersion 26
//noinspection GradleDependency
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    versionCode 62
    versionName "2.0.62"
    applicationId "com.android.embarkation"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    resValue "string", "releaseDate", "04/25/2018"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
        moduleName "recogDoc"
        ldLibs = ["android", "log", "jnigraphics"]
    }

}


ext {
    nativeDebuggable = true
}

def BASE_APP_ID = "com.dxp."
def AIRPORT_APP_ID = "airport"
def VALIDATE_APP_ID = "validate"
def ACI_APP_ID = "aci"

def GANGWAY_APP_ID = "gangway"
def BRAND_NCL = "ncl"
def BRAND_VV = "vv"
def BRAND_DXP = "dxp"
def ENV_INTEG = "Integ_"
def ENV_DEV = "Dev_"
def ENV_QA = "Qa_"
def ENV_SHIFT = "Shift_"
def ENV_SHIFT_QC = "ShiftQC_"
def ENV_DEMO = "Demo_"
def DXP_SUFFIX = "dxp_"




sourceSets {
    main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res-chat'
    main.jniLibs.srcDirs += 'src/main/libs'
}



productFlavors {

    devAirport {
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_DEV))
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_DEV)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    devValidate {
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_DEV)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    devAci {
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_DEV)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    gangwayDev {
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_DEV)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }

    gangwayQcShip {
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_QA)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }

    qcShipAirport {
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_QA)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    qcShipAci {
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_QA)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    qcShipValidate {
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_VV).concat(ENV_QA)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipGangway {
        versionCode 62
        versionName "2.1.62"
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_DEV)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }


    nclShipAirport {
        versionCode 62
        versionName "2.1.62"
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_DEV)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipValidate {
        versionCode 62
        versionName "2.1.62"
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_DEV)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipAci {
        versionCode 62
        versionName "2.1.62"
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_DEV)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipQcAirport {
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_INTEG)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipQcValidate {
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_INTEG)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipQcAci {
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_INTEG)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipQcGangway {
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_INTEG)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipQcPremAirport {
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_QA)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipQcPremValidate {
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_QA)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipQcPremAci {
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_QA)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShipQcPremGangway {
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_QA)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShiftShipAirport {
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_SHIFT)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShiftShipValidate {
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_SHIFT)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShiftShipAci {
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_SHIFT)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShiftShipGangway {
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_SHIFT)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShiftQCShipAirport {
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_SHIFT_QC)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShiftQCShipValidate {
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_SHIFT_QC)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShiftQCShipAci {
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_SHIFT_QC)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    nclShiftQCShipGangway {
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_SHIFT_QC)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }

    nclDemoAirport {
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_DEMO)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    nclDemoValidate {
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_DEMO)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    nclDemoAci {
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_DEMO)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    nclDemoGangway {
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_NCL).concat(ENV_DEMO)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }

    dxpAirportDemo {
        def APK_NAME = AIRPORT_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_DXP).concat(ENV_DEMO)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(AIRPORT_APP_ID)
    }

    dxpValidateDemo {
        def APK_NAME = VALIDATE_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_DXP).concat(ENV_DEMO)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(VALIDATE_APP_ID)
    }

    dxpAciDemo {
        def APK_NAME = ACI_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_DXP).concat(ENV_DEMO)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(ACI_APP_ID)
    }

    dxpGangwayDemo {
        def APK_NAME = GANGWAY_APP_ID.concat("_").concat(BRAND_DXP).concat(ENV_DEMO)
        applicationId BASE_APP_ID.concat(GANGWAY_APP_ID)
    }



}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('keystore/debug.keystore')
    }
    release {
        storeFile file('keystore/release.keystore')
        storePassword "DeCurtis@Jaipur2018"
        keyAlias "DeCurtis"
        keyPassword "DeCurtis@Jaipur2018"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

lintOptions {
    // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
    quiet true
    // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
    abortOnError false
    // if true, only report errors
    ignoreWarnings true

    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->


    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        output.outputFileName = new File("./../../../../../build/apk/",
                "${DXP_SUFFIX}${variant.flavorName}_${versionName}.apk")
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}
dependencies {
def couchBaseDependencies = rootProject.ext.couchbaseDependancies
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// Logging API
compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-5') {
    // workaround issue #73
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
// IntegrationTests API
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
//    compile 'com.decurtis.android.nearbylibrary:nearbylibrary:1.0.1'
compile couchBaseDependencies.couchbaselite
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile project(path: ':cbutil')
compile 'com.decurtis.logger:logger:1.0.3@aar'
compile project(path: ':cbutil')
compile project(':psync2')

compile files('libs/rfidsdk.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'ru.alexbykov:nopaginate:0.4.3'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.0.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'uk.co.alt236:bluetooth-le-library-android:1.0.0'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-5'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.0'
compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'

annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.4.0'
compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.3'
compile 'q.rorbin:badgeview:1.1.0'
compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.0.9'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'
// Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
compile 'com.myhexaville:smart-image-picker:1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.decurtis.chatframework:chatframework:1.0.10@aar'
compile 'com.decurtis.logger:logger:1.0.8@aar'
compile project(path: ':cbutil')
compile project(':psync2')
compile 'com.dxp.barcodereader:DXPCameraBarcodeLibrary:1.0.5@aar'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.decurtis.nearbybeacon:nearbybeacon:1.0.16@aar'
compile 'com.dxp.passportreader:passportreader:1.0.10@aar'
compile 'com.kontaktio:sdk:4.0.0'
compile project(':rules-engine')
compile project(':rules-entities')
compile files('libs/rules.jar')
compile(group: 'com.dxp.mrzreaderlib', name: 'mrzreaderlib', version: '1.0.3', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The root cause is that 2 libraries are using the same dependencies.

This often occurs when a library embedded another library (such as a [fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar)) but you also declare it as a dependency (i.e. via the word `compile`)

In your case, you have 2 (or more) libraries using  `com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferencequeue` which, after a short googling, correspond to [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/FinalizableReferenceQueue.java), and is one of your dependencies.

An easy solution would be to remove the line `compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'`.

But if you want to know how to fix your problem, you can run the dependencies task for your app. Here `app` refers to the name of the module under the project.

```
// run gradlew which is on your root project.

// linux / osx
./gradlew app:dependencies

// windows
gradlew app:dependencies
```

This will print all the configuration and its dependencies. To narrow down, you can focus on only one build by adding for example `--configuration debugCompileClasspath` or with a flavor named myFlavor `--configuration myFlavorDebugCompileClasspath` (case sensitive).

You should now be able to see which other libraries is using guava and exclude it like :

```
compile(<dependency_path>) { //works also with project(<proj_name>)
    exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava" 
}
```

(see more about [exclude](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude-java.util.Map-))

Comment: Very nice answer. I am working on this now .. will keep you posted !