# Eclipse doesn't show content of jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I created a combined Jar file containing classes and different jars, using eclipse. I added the Jar file in build path of a project as an external archive. Now eclipse doesn't allow me to see or import the classes inside these jar files. [Here's the link of that eclipse is showing me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFWmN.png)

How can I view and import the .class files inside these jars?

Comment: you cannot put a bunch of jar files into a single "combined" jar like that. Why don't you put all those jar s into a lib folder and add that lib folder to the classpath?

Comment: @Daniele I tried using a One-Jar too but getting into the same problem

Comment: @Daniele http://one-jar.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your One-JAR (also called [fat JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19150811/6505250)) contains **nested JARs instead of the `.class` files** that are contained in these JARs.

When creating the `combined.jar` JAR file, make sure that the `.class` files are not zipped twice (e. g. unzip all JAR files into the same folder without creating extra subfolders and then zip the content of this folder as `combined.jar`).