# Package not found while running Verticle from command line

Tags: java, maven, vert.x

I'm using `Maven` and `Vert.x` to create an application. 
Everything is working fine while I run it in my IDE (IntelliJ) but I can't make it work using command line.

I have a `Launcher` class that deploy some verticles but the problem is the same with all my verticles.

So far here is what I've tried:

```
vertx run Launcher.java
vertx run com.packagename.Launcher.java
// user-content-service-0.1.jar create via: mvn clean package
run com.packagename.Launcher.java -cp target\user-content-service-0.1.jar
```

As error I get this:

```
.../path/Launcher.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
private static final Logger logger = logManager.getLogger(Launcher.class);

symbol: variable LogManager
location: class com.packagename.Launcher
java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed
...
```

The issue seems to come from the fact that the compiler is not able to find dependancies

Here is what my `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.packagename</groupId>
  <artifactId>user-content-service</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <name>Project - user-content-service</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <vertx.version>[3.5.0,3.6)</vertx.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <log4j.version>[2.10.0,2.11)</log4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-unit</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-config</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>guru.nidi.raml</groupId>
      <artifactId>raml-tester</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And that's my `Launcher.java` file:

```
package com.packagename;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle; import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager; import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Launcher extends AbstractVerticle {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Launcher.class);

    @Override
    public void start() {
        vertx.deployVerticle("com.packagename.DynamoDBVerticle", logRes -> {
            if (logRes.succeeded()) {
                vertx.deployVerticle("com.packagename.UploaderVerticle", uploaderRes -> {
                    if (uploaderRes.succeeded()) {
                        vertx.deployVerticle("com.packagename.ServerVerticle", serverRes -> {
                            if (!serverRes.succeeded()) {
                                logger.error("Could not start server");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        logger.error("Could not start uploader");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                logger.error("Could not start Dynamo");
            }
        });
    } }
```

Any clue what could I be doing wrong here ?

Thanks !

Comment: First recommendation is to stop using `LATEST` cause it's long time deprecated...and you can't run it from command line cause you haven't packaged all dependencies into a fat-jar (maven-assembly-plugin) or something similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a classpath issue; because you package your jarfile with maven-jar in the package phase, you are only getting that in the build directory; if you want to run on the command-line with `java -jar`, you should create a [fat-jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar) (aka uber-jar, a jar file specifically packaged in order for it to contain your classes and all dependencies declared in the pom file).

You can add the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to do that in the package phase, ie:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                <Main-Verticle>com.packagename.Launcher</Main-Verticle>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <artifactSet/>
        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note: you have a class name clash between the vert.x Launcher (used as Main-Class, in the fat-jar), and your own Launcher (which is actually a Verticle): I'd suggest to rename it.

After `maven package`, you will be then able to do:

```
java -jar target/user-content-service-0.1-fat.jar
```

Check in the [vert.x samples](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/maven-verticles/maven-verticle) for more information.

Comment: Please use an more recent version of maven-shade-plugin See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ furthermore remove the configuration for the `outputFile` and keep the conventions...