# Runnable (console) jar application

Tags: java, jelastic

EDIT: crap. I only included Jelastic as a tag but forgot to mention that my app is hosted at a Jelastic provider.

I have more or less no experience (only Heroku) with cloud/web hosting services but I haven't found any answer to my (probably) simple question.

Right now all I need is to deploy is a simple runnable jar. I've chosen Java Engine as the environment. I uploaded a jar from my computer and.... it already runs - which surprised me a lot. I check the `run.log` and it appears that a Spring Boot app called `jelastic-helloworld-1.1.war` (which was provided after initializing the Java Engine) is run, which itself loads my jar. That's nice, thank you.

I'm curious though, how my jar can be run without loading it through the provided Spring Boot app? That is, running it with `java -jar app.jar`

Comment: Can you use the Heroku's maven plugin? https://github.com/heroku/heroku-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Engine software stack is an image of a base CentOS template by Jelastic PaaS with the preinstalled JDK. It provides a bare minimum required for Java application hosting, while ensuring compatibility with all of the platform features (e.g. automated vertical and horizontal scaling, public IP, isolation groups, firewall rules, API and SSH access, etc).

Java Engine is designed for the deployment and hosting of Java applications based on the **fat JAR / uber JAR** (**i.e. executable JAR with all the classes, resources, and dependencies**).
In details about this software stack, you can read [here](https://docs.jelastic.com/java-engine).
More information about the **fat JAR** you can read in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar).