# Does go modules provide a mechanism like maven's scope?

Tags: go, go-modules

Saying I'm developing a plugin `p` of a system `A`, so `p` naturally depends on `A` when developing and testing.

But this kind of dependency is not necessary once `p` integrated with `A`. In maven the dependency can be claimed with a `provided` scope to avoid unnecessary version conflict.

How could this to be achieved in go modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. But this is not much of a problem. Say you have `foo_test.go`, which includes a dependency of to `foo/bar/baz`. Now, this dependency will only be [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) into the test binary `go test`compiles on the fly. It will not be included into the "main" binary.

This is one advantage of Go - the compiler identifies what needs to be linked and using Go modules, he has a bill of material which not only defines the required dependency by name, but down to the very commit.

As written, think of the content of `go.mod` more like a bill of materials which are needed at one point or the other when working with the project and not like a set of instructions to build a [fat JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar).

Side note: even maven dependencies typically do not go into the resulting JAR. Spring Boot does this, but that is NOT the default maven behavior; building [skinny JARs](https://dzone.com/articles/the-skinny-on-fat-thin-hollow-and-uber) is.

Comment: But what if I include the dependency `foo/bar/baz` in normal code, not int test code?