# Maven with OpenJDK 11.0.2 and BouncyCastleProvider

Tags: maven, bouncycastle, noclassdeffounderror, java-11

1. Maven builds properly

   # mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.help.idea -DartifactId=client -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false

   # mvn install:install-file -Dfile=rs2xml.jar -DgroupId=net.proteanit.sql  -DartifactId=rs2xml -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

   # mvn package
2. But while ***running the jar*** it gives following error

   ```
   java -jar target/client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
       at com.help.idea.authen.ClientMain.main(ClientMain.java:76)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
   ```

I have following  `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.help.idea</groupId>
  <artifactId>client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>client</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jgoodies/jgoodies-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgoodies-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jgoodies/forms -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
    <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.65</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbutils/commons-dbutils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis -->
<dependency>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.help.idea.authen.ClientMain</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Tried many suggestion from google but could not get it right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the full pom, or at least the context around the dependencies

Comment: How is your jar packaged before being run through the command line?

Comment: Can you add scope to your dependencies. This should help you.<scope>provided</scope>

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackOverflow.  The error message tells you that your class `ClientMain` can't access the class `BouncyCastleProvider`. A likely cause for this is that the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) that you launched doesn't see the JAR that contains that class. Such JARs would have to be mentioned with [the `--class-path` option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Looking at your launch command, you can see that there's no class path being specified. One way to fix this, is to enumerate all your direct and transitive dependencies with the `--class-path` option (although that's a lot of work).

On the other hand, it is possible that this project created a so-called [*fat JAR*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19150811/2525313), which contains all dependencies. That one, you could launch with just such a short command. Have a look into the `target` folder and see whether there's another JAR that you can use to launch. Probably something with `-jar-with-dependencies` in its name (don't launch anything with `sources` or `javadoc` in their name, that's pointless).

If this doesn't fix your problem, please follow [Darren's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254401/maven-with-openjdk-11-0-2-and-bouncycastleprovider#comment108363411_61254401) and show us the full pom, so we can see the entire context.

Comment: Thanks. Adding classpath does not solve the issue. I am exploring options to make a fat JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all the responses. I need to learn a lot. you may please refine my answer.
I now created a directory "src/main/resources" and put org/bouncycastle/ in there. Now things are working as expected. But things should have worked directly with maven build.

Comment: Maven information like the build-path is only available inside Maven - that is here, while building.   If you need it later, like when you run the generated output, you need to explicitly save it with your generated output.   Note that if you tell maven to run your program, it will work.