# How can I make fat execuatable file in CMAKE?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am newbie on CMAKE. I am trying to make "fat executable file".

The term, fat executeable file, I mentioned, is a executable binary file which contains all shared libraries and can be just run in another environment.

## Example (Trouble Situation)

There is ComputerA which is a computer that I used for developing. There is GCC, Boost libraries, librados etc.

And there is ComputerB which is a computer that I wanted to execute the binary that I built.

* Of course, Both Computer A and B have some conditions. Same Intel CPU Arch. (i7), Same CentOS.

I built binary file in ComputerA using CMAKE with this command, `cmake .. && make`. And I copied this file to ComputerB and executed.

When I execute the copied binary file in Computer B, it said like below.

```bash
[root@ComputerB ~]# ./binaryFile 123.123.123.123
./binaryFile: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_json.so.1.80.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I understand what this error message say. There is no shared library which it needed. So, what I want to ask in this community is, **What is CMAKE Command for containing shared libraries**.

### Similar thing :: fat JAR

The reason, why I called "fat executable file", is that there is [a word "fat JAR" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar). I am not familiar with Java. But it is commonly used word in Java community.

## My CMAKE File

It contains some libraries like Boost, Rados, RBD etc. (There will be more according to progress of developing)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)
project(BinaryHelper VERSION 0.1.0)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS json)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lrados -std=c++17")

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    utils/binary.cpp
    utils/message.cpp
    utils/header.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    rados
    rbd
    Threads::Threads
)
```

Comment: [Fat binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary) means something else. You either need static linking, or copy the libraries separately. You can install them as packages, or copy them manually.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh Thanks. I am searching with the keyword "boost static link" and trying. However, like ```rados```, how can I copy them manually?

Comment: You just copy them. Get the list of libs usind `ldd`. You can place them in `/usr/local/lib` for them to be found automatically, or in a custom directory if you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or rpath.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well, actually I just want to send only ONE file and it is execuable well. In your answer, There is no solution that I wanted. (for rados, rbd or something else) right?

Comment: Then try static linking?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks. It works. I am going to write the solution in my question.

Comment: For more complex applications, there's always [exodus](https://github.com/intoli/exodus) or similar application packer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat, I solved the problem with static link.

## Modified CMAKE

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)
project(BinaryHelper VERSION 0.1.0)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS json)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lrados -std=c++17")

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_library(
    boost_json
    STATIC
    IMPORTED
)

set_target_properties(
    boost_json
    PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/lib/libboost_json.a
)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    utils/binary.cpp
    utils/message.cpp
    utils/header.cpp
)

# target_link_libraries (
#     ${PROJECT_NAME}
#     ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
#     rados
#     rbd
#     Threads::Threads
# )

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    boost_json
    rados
    rbd
    Threads::Threads
)
```

There is additional(modified) keywords, `add_library`, `set_target_properties`, `target_link_libraries`.