# Why I can't run JAR File in another position in my computer?

Tags: java, file, jar, executable-jar

I have created a JAR file, it is in "out" folder of my project, at this time the format of this file is Executable Jar File, but when I copy this file to another folder it cannot run and it says error unable to access jar file, now the format of the file is JAR file but it isn't executable jar file.

I hope to be able to keep the format of the file as executable jar file so that it can be executed on another machine at any time.

I hope someone can help me with this error and explain why it is giving me this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a fat JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar)

Comment: It depends of the jar structure, You may add the tool used to generate the jar (maven-jar plugin, spring boot, other...) and also what you tried, what is the error message, anything you think may be relevant for us to help you

Comment: How are you attempting to run the .jar file?  Where, exactly, are you seeing the “unable to access jar file” message?