# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>       File1: C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
>       File3: C:\Users\USER.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Duplicate lib file copied in APK-META-INF/license.txt " error in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912459/duplicate-lib-file-copied-in-apk-meta-inf-license-txt-error-in-android-studio)

Comment: @waki where do I find that

Comment: @noname: he already provided the link above.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.