# Android gradle build gives DuplicateFileException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hi after adding apache poi gradle build , Im getting this expection. Could you please explain me what it is how to resolve it.

I have tried excluding package options in many ways, didn't worked

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.9'

}
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>       File1: /home/surendra/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.9/4c514498f0e82cccfdd3208b9caff2f45158db4a/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
>       File2: /home/surendra/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/bbe83c739d22eecfacd06d7e0b99ba13277040ed/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
>       File3: /home/surendra/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.poi/poi/3.9/5d5e41354e88322e4bc590b31f3d2d1d52b3e6ac/poi-3.9.jar

Comment: Perhaps the problem is solved with the replacement of com.github.dextorer:sofa:1.0.0  instead of   compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.9'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this exclude the duplicated file by using below code

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `build.gradle` file and add the following line:

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
  }
```

In my case I had to add like this one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'    
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6"


}
```

For better reference visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31912566/1276495).

Answer (score 0):

exclude the duplicated file by adding this to you gradle file

```
    android {
        ...
        packagingOptions {
                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            }
}
```