# Runtime error in my android app

Tags: android, jar, android-gradle-plugin, objectmapper, google-analytics-firebase

whenever I want to wrapp some data in a jackson object mapper, I got a runtime error with following message:

07-07 17:44:59.049 19642-20156/com.app.teamchannel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
                                                                     **java.lang.VerifyError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper**

First time I encountered this error was after I included google analytics in gradle like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
```

Can anyone help please? I've already spent couple of hours with no solution until now.

Complete exception:

```
Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector', referenced from method org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.
Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider', referenced from method org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.
Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.util.TokenBuffer', referenced from method org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert
Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext', referenced from method org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._createDeserializationContext
Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter', referenced from method org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._defaultPrettyPrinter
FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
 java.lang.VerifyError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
     at com.app.teamchannel.adapters.MySyncAdapter.onPerformSync(MySyncAdapter.java:2205)
     at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:247)

FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
 java.lang.VerifyError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
     at com.app.teamchannel.adapters.MySyncAdapter.onPerformSync(MySyncAdapter.java:2205)
     at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:247)
```

Comment: please add the complete stacktrace (from logcat) to your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/100107/794088 might help

Comment: there are explanations how those problems are caused but no clear solution to solve them. What should I do?

Comment: ty for the stacktrace!   can you also post the your complete `dependencies {...}` that is in your gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. There was obviously a package name collision, what lead to take the wrong classes during runtime.

**What I did**:

I downloaded both jars manually

- jackson-core-asl-1.9.3
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13

and changed the package name from org.codehaus.jackson.** to custom.org.codehaus.jackson.@1 for both libraries. To change the package name I used a tool called [JarJar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jarjar/downloads).

You can find instructions how to repackage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612726/using-jarjar-repackaging-tool).

After that I put the repackaged jars into libs folder which you find in app folder (Android Studio: project view).
Following code must be included in the build.gradle on app-level in the dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

So gradle also compiles jars in the lib folder.