# Duplicate class names in two external third party obfuscated libraries

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project that includes two external third party libraries.  Both these libraries have the class file names obfuscated and gradle barfs when trying to build the project.

```
Duplicate class a.a.a.a.a.b found in modules...
```

I can't exclude any classes, as they are not duplicates, nor do I see a way for gradle to prefix the names.

Any easy fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/master/README.md) to [relocate the offending packages](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/). You'd then depend on the shadowed jar instead of the original

```
plugins {
   id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.2.0"
}
configurations {
   shadowMe { transitive = false } 
} 
dependencies {
   shadowMe 'foo:jar-to-shadow:1.0'
   compile files({tasks.shadowJar})
}
task shadowJar(type: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar) {
   archiveBaseName = 'shadowed-foo' 
   relocate 'a.a.a.a.a', 'shadow.a.a.a.a'
   from zipTree(configurations.shadowMe.singleFile)
}
```

None of this tested and possibly needs some tweaking but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the shadow plugin while researching and thought there must be a better way.

Comment: The only other solution would involve loading each jar with a different classloader (or loading each in a separate jvm)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with Install Referrer and ARCore (both from Google!)

I wasn't able to get ShadowJar working with an `aar` library (which contains a `classes.jar`). Maybe there's some way to do it, but I couldn't figure it out.

Instead, I downloaded and unzipped the aar, used [jarjar](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar) to rename the offending class in `classes.jar`, and zipped it back into an `aar`. Then I put my modified `aar` file in my `libs` directory and modified my dependency to reference that local file instead of a maven library.

More detailed explanation:
To fix the classes.jar, I renamed it to classes-original.jar, created a `jarjar.rules` file containing:

```
rule a.a.a relocated-a.a.a
```

and ran:

```
java -jar jarjar-1.4.jar process jarjar.rules classes-original.jar classes.jar
```

Comment: Hello, i'm currently running into the exact same issue with installReferrer and ARCore (with Unity). Do you remember the steps/commands you've used to resolve the problem? If so, do you mind sharing them? Would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. P.S: In my case. the duplicate class is "a.a.a". Was it the same for you?

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this problem: Usage of the tool is explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33592560