# Users required to install maven to execute uber jars?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, uberjar

I have been told that to create an executable jar that includes other jars automatically is to use maven's uber jars.

Do users have to also install maven to execute uber jars?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Thank you for looking Jigar Joshi!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar  Do you happen to know of an alternative to uber jars?  Can you help with this?  Thank you so much in advance!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097571/webserver-websocket-server-in-a-jar

Comment: uberjar is a big jar with all jar inside.

Comment: [How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven?rq=1)

Comment: Only Java is required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant an alternative to using maven to include jars automatically for the users.

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like any of the linked questions are the same. Two of them are asking how to deliberately require a dependency. One of them asks what an ubjerjar is. Another asks a question whose answer is to use an uberjar. This one is asking whether installing Maven is required in order to execute ubjerjars created by it. Correct me if I overlooked something, but as far as I can tell, not only are the questions not the same, none of their answers address this question.

Comment: @AdiInbar Thought the same thing.  Registered my reopen.  Got my answer.  I'm good.  Love your personal page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Maven shade plugin will simply copy all files from the dependencies' jars to the uber jar (and warn you about conflicts), so this is a normal jar file that can be executed independently.