# How to deploy java jersey and Grizzly on Windows Server

Tags: java, maven, jersey, grizzly

I have developed jersey web service server on mac os x. I have been testing by running it using maven command line: `mvn exec:java` and it works just fine. I'm currently running my web services in grizzly.

Now i would need to deploy to Windows Server 2008. What should I do?

I have been reading the deployment documentation on jersey [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html).

1. Do I need to follow section 4.2(JAX-RS Application Model) to 4.4(Configuring the Classpath Scanning)?
2. Do i just run the maven command line in windows? ie: `mvn exec:java`
3. Do I need to compile into a jar file? I have tried compiling into jar file but I encounter errors.

This is how I compiled the jar file: `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package`
This is how i ran the jar file: `java -jar application.jar`. Here is the error:

> MyName-MacBook-Pro:target myname$ java -jar
>   application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServer  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 6 more

Here is the content of my pom.xml:

> http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>
> ```
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>
> <groupId>org.company</groupId>
> <artifactId>application</artifactId>
> <packaging>jar</packaging>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
> <name>application</name>
>
> <dependencyManagement>
>     <dependencies>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
>             <version>${jersey.version}</version>
>             <type>pom</type>
>             <scope>import</scope>
>         </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
> </dependencyManagement>
>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support:
>      <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>4.9</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>
>   <!--  Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
>     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
>     <version>2.2.4</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>
>   </dependency>
>
>   <dependency>            <groupId>mysql</groupId>            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>       <version>5.1.6</version>        </dependency>
>           <!-- Apache Log4J -->       <dependency>            <groupId>log4j</groupId>            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>          <version>1.2.17</version>
>   </dependency>
>       </dependencies>
>
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.5.1</version>
>             <inherited>true</inherited>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>1.7</source>
>                 <target>1.7</target>
>                 <archive>
>                   <manifest>
>                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
>                       <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
>                       <mainClass>org.company.Main</mainClass>
>                   </manifest>
>               </archive>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>             <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>1.2.1</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>java</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>             <configuration>
>                 <mainClass>org.company.Main</mainClass>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>           <configuration>
>             <archive>
>               <manifest>
>                   <mainClass>org.company.Main</mainClass>
>               </manifest>
>             </archive>
>           </configuration>            </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
>
> <properties>
>     <jersey.version>2.7</jersey.version>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
> </properties> </project>
> ```

Comment: anyone has any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **Apache Maven Shade Plugin** (or a similar plugin) to build your **[Uber Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11947093/3811473)** (a jar with all dependencies included). Then take this jar to your server and run with:

`java -jar bla.jar PATH_TO_POSSIBLE_CONFIG_FILE`

Comment: If you include a working example I'll change my downvote to an upvote. But this does not help in its current form.