# mvn clean install doens't find package

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have 2 maven projects; the first one has this pom:

```
<groupId>deseuri</groupId>
<artifactId>sim-common</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<name>sim-common</name>
<dependencies>
    /*
        dependencies
    */
</dependencies>
```

In the second project, I want to use the first one as a dependency, like this:

```
 <groupId>utils</groupId>
 <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.1</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>deseuri</groupId>
        <artifactId>sim-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    // other depdencies
</dependencies>
```

The first project build successfully with "mvn clean install", and it creates a jar file in my local maven repository (in .m2), but when I run clean install on the second project it says:

```
 package ro.sim.commonApp.model does not exist
```

...which is in the first project.

P.S.: If I choose "Make project" from Intellij Idea (which creates the source files in the target folder) and then run clean install it works fine.

Thanks, 
Tekin.

Comment: no, when I tried "make project" from idea. This was due to an error of mine: I declared the source in project settings to be in the src folder, but maven wanted it to be in src/main/java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your util project has an jar packaging, then from the description above you are trying to make an **uber jar** [What is an uber jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar). To manage it in a correct way you can use [Shade plugn](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to create an uber jar, I just want this jar to be created and the dependency to be available at runtime. I tried adding the "runtime" and "provided" scope to the common dependency, but it doesn't actually do what I want. Any ideas on this?:)

Comment: In that case you have to suggest what is your new classpath (the place where this libraries live), otherwise java is not able to get your dependencies

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I don't want the dependency to be included in my jar, I want it to get the dependency from the classpath, whichever that may be. Can this be done?

Comment: Ok, but you have to indicate where are these dependencies?