# NoSuchMethodError for "list.toMap" in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

When I ran with spark-submit for the following simple Spark program of:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark._
import SparkContext._

object TEST2{
def main(args:Array[String])
{
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST")
  val sc=new SparkContext(conf)

  val list=List(("aa",1),("bb",2),("cc",3))
  val maps=list.toMap
}

}
```

I got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for the line of "val maps=list.toMap".
But in a spark-shell or simply scala, it has no problem:

```
scala> val list=List(("aa",1),("bb",2),("cc",3))
list: List[(String, Int)] = List((aa,1), (bb,2), (cc,3))

scala> val maps=list.toMap
maps: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(aa -> 1, bb -> 2, cc -> 3)
```

So to use "toMap" method, what am I missing in spark-submit? I use "sbt package" to compile the program and without problem. Thanks!

P.S: the build.sbt file is as:

```
name := "TEST2"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include the full error message in the question.

Comment: i executed your code against my spark-1.2.0 &scala 2.10.4 , it worked without any errors on spark-submit.  try  scalaVersion := "2.10.4" in sbt. Note : till date spark-all-versions are buit against 2.10.4, not  2.11.x

Comment: Changed to 2.10.4 but still the same. Did you set specially to your CLASSPATH? But "toMap" is a so basic method in scala, quite weird that it could be found by spark-submit. I tested on each node that this method works fine.

Comment: I had the same problem on Spark 1.3.0 (CDH 5.4.4) but setting the scala version to 2.10.4 _did_ fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

`sbt package` creates a JAR containing **only** your project, not all its dependencies.

When using `spark-submit`, you need a JAR that contains your project and all dependencies **except** Spark libraries (already provided by the Spark installation on your cluster)

This [uber-JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar) can be created using the [sbt assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly):

- In your project folder, create the file `project/assembly.sbt` with this line :

`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.0")`

- In your `build.sbt`, the Spark dependencies should be tagged as "provided":

  ```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
    "org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
    ...
  )
  ```
- Run `sbt assembly`, which will create the uber-JAR `target/scala-2.11/TEST2-1.0.jar`