# Error after Maven Package

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-package

a Project of mine using Commons Chain works fine, when i run it in the IDE.
Now i tried to package it with maven.

I used the following pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <finalName>NAME</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-chain</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-chain</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

As you can see i added the Main Class to my manifest and specified the Dependencies to use.

The package process runs throught, but when i start the jar it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/ch
ain/impl/ChainBase
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

**Where does this error come from/what do i need to change in my config file?**

Greetings,

Nicolas

Comment: Perhaps you have the missing dependency added by the IDE, in the .project file. Maven ignores such imports.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. I don't have a .project File. Is there a similar thing for IntelliJ?

Comment: Not sure, I am not familiar with it. I had the same problem once in Eclipse as you can manually add libraries to the classpath (but Maven does not care about them). If not a .project file perhaps another setting that modifies the build path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a classpath that has the jar files for your dependencies, something like `java -cp=libs -jar main.jar` where `libs` contains the dependency jar files. Maven will set that up for you with the [maven-exec-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/): `mvn exec:java -DmainClass=main.Main`. Maybe what you want is to have Maven create an "uber jar" that includes all of the class files for your dependencies so that `java -jar main.jar` just works. Use the maven-assembly-plugin or the maven-shade-plugin to create one. See [What is an uber jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar).

Comment: Interesting. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/ looks close to what i need.

Comment: You are a god :P Worked!

Comment: I'll keep to my place as a mere creature. :) Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maven [doesn't add the classpath to a jar by default](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Add).

You need to tell maven-jar-plugin to do that by adding an addClasspath entry to its configuration/archive block.

```
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
```

(this should be immediately before or after the `mainClass` line)

Comment: Thank you, i tried that. Unfortunally it did not help. I still get the same error.