# running maven jars in java files

Tags: java, maven

I have a situation of running a jar file. I have added the jar file in maven repo and added the dependency in my pom. I am trying to run following command in java file using process executer.

pom dependency:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vmware.vcac.qe.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>vcac-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code in java:

```
String command = "java -cp " + jarPath + " " + className + " " + propertiesFilePath;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I want to get the jar file path from maven. What should be the value of `jarPath` in above `command` string?

Comment: How do you package your project?

Comment: as a jar <packaging>jar</packaging>

Comment: Have you package your dependency with your project into a same jar file or separate?

Comment: I added that jar in maven repo and use as a dependency in my pom. So I think my project jar is packaged separately.

Comment: How would you run your project?

Comment: project dir > mvn clean install -f pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Technically the path to your maven installed artifacts should be something like

```
<user_home_dir>/.m2/repository/com/vmware/vcac/qe/tools/vcac-tools/1.0.0/vcac-tools-1.0.0.jar
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But the problem here is I don't want to hard code the whole path. Is there any way to get this path in java using some get system/maven property?

Comment: Another way would be to package the jar with your application. That way it will be available at the classpath of your application and you may be able to access there. What you need is a something similar to a [Uber jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar).