# Maven: How to include my external jar into build executable jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I am writing Spring app and I have two external jars there. It works in IDE, but when I building the executable jar with maven it fails with error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: to my external jars. How can I solve this? My dependency in pom file is:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.myappawsprovider</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyAppProvider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/Users/Projects/Java/MyApp/MyAppProvider/target/MyAppProvider Provider-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

I build it just with men package.

Comment: You can refer to this: [How to add local jar files in maven project?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955695/2201637)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your external jars are not present in the central maven repo, you can always add them to your local maven repo with below command

```
mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=[path of local maven repo] -DcreateChecksum=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=[jar file path] -DgroupId=[xxx] -DartifactId=[yyy] -Dversion=[zzz]
```

You can then add proper dependencies for these external jars in your pom.xml.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Add the jar to maven local repository first.
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile="path of jar" -DgroupId="com.external.jar" -DartifactId="externalJar" -Dversion="version of your jar" -Dpackaging=jar`In pom.xml of your project add the dependency -
     `<dependency>
         <groupId>com.external.jar</groupid>
         <artifactId>externalJar</artifactId>
        <version>version of your jar</version>
     </dependency>`
[Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `maven-assembly-plugin` with `jar-with-dependencies` `descriptorRef` as specified below in your pom.xml `<buid><plugins>...</plugins></build>`section. It creates the [uber jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar) with all required dependencies.
See the configuration section [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)

```
<build>
   <plugins> 
       <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

You can also use the `maven-shade-plugin` as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html).