# What is Embedded servers and Embedded Java library?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, server, infinispan

While learn about Spring-Boot and Infinispan, I heard about words like Embedded server and Embedded Java library. What are these. How they differ from normal servers and normal Java library?

Answer (score 1):

An embedded java server is server that is shipped within the application. So when you run the main method, the application server gets started with the application running into.

The main difference to a normal java-server is, that you start just the jar, instead of installing an server first and then deploying the war in it.

---

An Embedded Java library is a jar that is embedded into an other jar. Normally this is done simply by extracting the libary-jar(s) and the its contents into an new jar, togeher with your application (often called a [uber-jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar) (or über-jar))). *Spring boot do it different!: it does not extract the jar and put it content into the container/outer/über - jar, instead it put the not exploded jar into the container-jar.*