# Exclude files from an Uber Jar built with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have a Maven project in IntelliJ. And I am building an [Uber JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar) directly from the IDE. I would like to exclude certain files (*.rsa) from the Uber Jar but I am not able to find how to configure this. If the Uber Jar was packaged using maven and the maven-shade-plugin then it is possible to filter out files. But IntelliJ seems to be using something different behind the scenes to build the Uber Jar. This can be configured via the Artifact Configuration editor. But this editor does not provide any means to exclude files. And the schema of the _jar.xml file which this editor produces is kept secret somewhere. So how can I exclude files from an Uber Jar in IntelliJ?

Comment: What's an "Uber Jar?"  Should we know what that is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar

Comment: If the idea of having an Uber JAR is to contain everything (artifact & dependencies), why are you trying to exclude files. They should either be part of the artifact or dependencies or not part of the project(?).
Can you clarify your intentions as there may be a different solution that's better suited to your needs?

Comment: I end up with ECLIPSEF.SF and ECLIPSEF.RSA files in my Uber Jar and I suppose these come from one of the dependencies, which I cannot pinpoint. These files should not be in my Uber Jar as they are preventing it from executing. This is why I am trying to exclude them somehow.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?