# Make NON-FAT jar in Gradle on-demand

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I'm using Gradle. Usually I'm build the FAT jar. There was no problem, but at this time, I also need to make NON-FAT jar.
I mean I want to exclude all depended library and run jar with `-cp` option like the following:

`java -cp "/sample1/lib/myjar.jar:/sample2/lib/depended.jar" com.example.main.Runner`

(In FAT jar, `java -jar myjar.jar` is the same thing and its contains `depended.jar`)

Here is my `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

jar.baseName = 'myjar'
version = ''
def mainClass = 'com.example.main.Runner'
mainClassName =  mainClass

def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
  flatDir dirs: "${projectDir}/libs"
}

dependencies {
  compile ':commons-chain:1.2'
  compile ':commons-io:2.4'

  testCompile ':junit:4.12'
  testCompile ':hamcrest-core:1.3'
}
jar {
  manifest {
      attributes 'Implementation-Version': version,
                 'Main-Class': mainClass
  }
  from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
}
```

I still want to keep this for usual FAT jar creation.
So, I tried to append a task like the following:

TRY #1

```
task makeSlimJar {
  jar.baseName = 'myjar.slim'
  jar {
  manifest {
      // remove main class
      attributes 'Implementation-Version': version
  }
  from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
}
```

TRY #2

```
task makeSlimJar {
  jar.baseName = 'myjar.slim'  
  jar {
  manifest {
      // remove main class
      attributes 'Implementation-Version': version
  }
  from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}

  tasks.Jar.execute()
}
```

TRY #3

```
task makeSlimJar {
  jar.baseName = 'myjar.slim'
  jar {
  manifest {
      // remove main class
      attributes 'Implementation-Version': version
  }
  from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
  dependsOn Jar 
}
```

After appended it, I ran the `gradle makeSlimJar`.
All of the above my tries were failed(programmatically, it were succeeded) and just created FAT jar with name  `myjar.slim.jar`.

Is there way to live together FAT and NON-FAT jar on the same `build.gradle` file?
... Or am I something wrong?

I consider that removing `apply plugin: 'application'` for NON-FAT jar is my last resort.

Please help me, if you could.

Thanks,

Comment: Just a note, recently far-jar is called uber jar in some communities.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code which is actually adding the dependencies to your jar is this line:

```
from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
```

your build script will normally build a 'slim jar' by default, except that you have added code to override this behaviour:

```
jar {
  manifest {
  attributes 'Implementation-Version': version,
             'Main-Class': mainClass
  }
  from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
}
```

**I would recommend removing these lines**.  When you run `gradle clean build` this will then build a normal jar (with no dependencies).

You could then add an additional task to create your 'fatjar' like this:

```
task fatjar << {
    jar.doFirst {
       println "creating fatjar"
       jar {
         from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
       }
    }
}
```

You can use this task to build the fatjar by running `gradle clean fatjar build`.

Alternatively you could try looking at a framework such as springboot, which would do all this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
According to your suggestion, I removed `jar{}` section and added `fatjar` task.
It works perfectly! Thank you so much.