# Program runs in Eclipse but running jar does not run

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar

I'm working java swing application.My program run successfully in Eclipse but when i create  running jar,it's does not opened.

[I created running jar like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGf8iiNBUjY)

In my option ,problem is that I'm using 4 jar library jmrtd.jar,Scuba.jar and etc.
What am I doing wrong? How i can create jar file,when I use some support libraries(jar files) ?

Comment: Why do you have the Maven tag? Are you using Maven for the build?

Comment: Sorry,i Mistaked @YMomb

Comment: Did you follow the video? Did you clicked on the generated .jar file? was there a JarFileName_lib folder?

Comment: You'll probably need to add your third-party jars to your executable jar. That's called an uber jar. Check this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar

Comment: Yes i followed this video . No.It's does not.I created only one main Jar file @Usagi Miyamoto

Comment: You have to add the content (except _META-INF/MANIFEST.MF_) of all required libraries (_jmrtd.jar_, _Scuba.jar_, etc.) into your main JAR to be able, to run it via double-click. (JARs are ZIP archives.)

Answer (score 0):

Please use option "Package required libraries into generated JAR"