# How to generate 2 jars in one java module: one is uber jar and another is non-uber jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I know I can achieve it via creating 2 modules, but just want to know is it possible to do tha it in one module ? Thanks

Comment: Maven Shade Plugin will _not_ suppress the creation of the "normal" JAR, so you get the desired behavior by default.

Comment: Then how do I refer to the normal jar if you I want to use it as dependency of another project. Because I notice only the uber jar is installed in local repo

Comment: You can use the `outputFile` config option. Please see below. In this case, your "normal" JAR will be installed/deployed and you can define the dependency as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven Shade Plugin, if you run the `shade` goal, will produce two JARs by default:

- `your-artifact.jar` — the Uber-JAR, and
- `original-your-artifact.jar` — the original, non-Uber-JAR.

---

Alternatively, you can specify a different name for the Uber-JAR by using the `outputFile` configuration option (see below). 
In this case, your "normal" JAR will have the "usual" name.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/uberjar-name.jar</outputFile>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

With this configuration, the results will be:

- `your-artifact.jar` — the original, non-Uber-JAR, and
- `uberjar-name.jar` — the Uber-JAR.

Comment: could you elaborate how this works in 1/2 sentences? What does the uber jar contain, and what the other? How is this determined / controlled? Very interesting Cheers!

Comment: @fl0w, this is perfectly explained in the following SO thread: [What is an uber jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11947037/2170192)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'll look into it.