# Google Cloud Dataproc drop BigQuery table not working

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Hi I tried to delete a table from BigQuery using  [java client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#bigquery_simple_app_all-java) in Dataproc, started spark-shell as below:

```sh
spark-shell --packages com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.59.0
```

and import following dependency

```scala
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.FieldValueList;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJobConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryResponse;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableResult;
import java.util.UUID;

val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService() 
bigquery.delete("test","temp")
```

here test and temp are my dataset and table name respectively but after running above statement it show following error:

```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
  at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:82)
  at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:88)
  at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:74)
  at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:75)
  at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
  at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.delete(BigQueryImpl.java:386)
  at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.delete(BigQueryImpl.java:375)
  ... 48 elided
```

Comment: check the access control https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

Comment: @Bira Thanks for sharing the link, I tried to set admin user and tried again but it shows same above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have on classpath an older [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) version (brought as Hadoop/Spark dependency) that does not have `MoreExecutors.directExecutor` method.

To fix this issue you need to include and [shade/relocate](https://forgegradle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/shading/) (to avoid conflicts with other libraries on classpath) `google-cloud-bigquery` library and its dependencies (including Guava) into your application's [UberJar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar).

[Here is](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/0e30d8af16b0100cc5645d143601e37bea7e886e/gcs/pom.xml#L258:L330) an example of how to do this using [Maven Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) plugin.