# Getting error while running Scala Spark code to list blobs in storage

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am getting below error while trying to list blobs using `google-cloud-storage` library:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

I have tried to change version of `google-cloud-storage` library in `build.sbt` but getting the same error again and again.

```scala
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials
import com.google.cloud.storage._
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobListOption

val credentials: GoogleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
val storage: Storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(projectId).build().getService()

val blobs =storage.list(bucketName, BlobListOption.currentDirectory(), BlobListOption.prefix(path))
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

logBuffered in Test := false

libraryDependencies ++=
  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % Test,
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
    "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.0",
    "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-storage" % "1.78.0"
  )
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because Spark uses older version of Guava library than `google-cloud-storage` library that doesn't have `Preconditions.checkArgument` method. This leads to `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception.

You can find more detailed answer and instructions on how to fix this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54312511/3227693).