# Installing playwright dependencies on ec2 to use it in Java

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, playwright

I'm trying to use playwright to generate pdfs in my java application. This is working fine locale but when deploying it on an ec2 using Beanstalk I get the following error:

```
Nov 11 09:17:32 ip-172-xx-xx-2 web: 2021-11-11 09:17:32.927 ERROR 17681 --- [io-5000-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error {
Nov 11 09:17:32 ip-172-xx-xx-2 web: message='Host system is missing dependencies!
Nov 11 09:17:32 ip-172-xx-xx-2 web: Missing libraries are:
Nov 11 09:17:32 ip-172-xx-xx-2 web: libatk-1.0.so.0
Nov 11 09:17:32 ip-172-xx-xx-2 web: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0
Nov 11 09:17:32 ip-172-xx-xx-2 web: libcups.so.2
Nov 11 09:17:32 ip-172-xx-xx-2 web: libxkbcommon.so.0
Nov 11 09:17:32 ip-172-xx-xx-2 web: libXcomposite.so.1
...
```

And of course, the error message is pretty straightforward. Dependencies are missing!
I already got to know that I can install these dependencies via the CLI tools, but I have no idea where to install it and how in my build process via CodePipeline with CodeBuild and CodeDeploy.
This is the command which you can find here: https://playwright.dev/java/docs/cli/#install-system-dependencies

```
mvn exec:java -e -Dexec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -Dexec.args="install-deps"
```

So the question is: Where and how do I install the Playwright dependency in my CodePipeline to run it on ec2 using beanstalk?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm ... what happens if you try to run `mvn install` from your ec2 instance ?

Comment: Also, you can just make a Docker image of your app and run it on EC2 in a Docker engine

Comment: I thought that with `mvn package` all necessary dependencies maven is aware of are packaged into the jar file

Comment: Changing the whole CD process to docker and going away from beanstalk is on the agenda but a little down the road

Comment: See my answer. Not always is it like this.

Comment: But where do I execute this command? The build is happening on one instance and the artifact of this build is deployed on an ec2 instance. On this one is no pom.xml accessible. Just the app.jar and I don't need the dependencies on the build instance right?

Comment: On the instace which build the jar

Comment: Added the `mvn install` before the packaging but it didn't work. Thank u though.

I think I need to install the dependencies on the ec2 instance before deploying

Answer (score 0):

> Dependencies are missing!

OK, so instead of having to worry about dependencies, why not just package them together with the code of your app into an [Uber Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar)

This can be done quiet easily using `mnv`.
You configure Maven to build a Fat JAR from your project by including the maven-assembly-plugin in your POM file's plugin section.

Add this to your `pom.xml`

```
configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

And then run `mvn clean package`. This will package your dependencies into your jar and it will be **impossible** for them to go missing.

Here's a [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html) with some more details on the topic

Does this solve your problem ? Let me know in the comments

Comment: Tried it but without any success. Thank u though

Comment: What's the output ? What's the contents of the JAR ? Do you get the same error when deploying ?

Comment: I'm pretty much stuck one step before. I'm not even able to deploy it because it's stuck in the pipeline with some weird errors that it's not possible to identify the jar. Locally I'm getting the same error as before