# Why do Apache-Storm org.apache.http.xxx imports work for local cluster but not for an actual storm cluster?

Tags: java, linux, apache-storm, apache-httpclient-4.x

I can run an apache-storm program in local mode (using Intellij and Maven), but when I run on the storm cluster it bombs immediately with the error "Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient". I have verified the storm cluster works on a toy program with no http calls. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
    <groupId>org.jmm</groupId> 
    <artifactId>twitter2</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0</version> 
    <dependencies> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId> 
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.1</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
            <version>2.6.3</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.json</groupId> 
            <artifactId>json</artifactId> 
            <version>20090211</version> 
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies> 
    <properties> 
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source> 
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target> 
    </properties> 
</project>
```

And the start of my spout code:

```
import org.apache.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector; 
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext; 
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer; 
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout; 
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields; 
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple; 
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values; 
import org.apache.storm.utils.Utils; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.Map; 
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; 
import java.time.LocalDateTime; import org.apache.http.HttpEntity; 
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse; 
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair; 
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; 
import org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs; 
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig; 
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet; 
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder; 
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients; 
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair; 
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils; 
import twitter4j.Status; 

public class twitterSpout extends BaseRichSpout { 
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector; 
    String bearerToken = "";   //deleted here, but filled in for my program 
    HttpGet httpGet; 
    HttpResponse response; 
    HttpEntity entity; 
    URIBuilder uriBuilder;
```

And the topology:

```
import org.apache.storm.Config; 
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter; 
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder; 
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields; 
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster; 

public class twitterTopology { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        twitterSpout spout = new twitterSpout(); 
        System.out.println("\nafter initializing twitterSpout\n"); 
        LossyBolt countBolt = new LossyBolt(); 
        ReportBolt reportBolt = new ReportBolt(); 
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder(); 
        builder.setSpout("twitterSpout", spout); 
        builder.setBolt("lossy", countBolt).fieldsGrouping("twitterSpout", new Fields("bucket")); 
        builder.setBolt("report", reportBolt).fieldsGrouping("lossy", new Fields("bcurrent")); 
  
        Config config = new Config(); 
        config.setDebug(true); 
        config.setNumWorkers(3); 
        /* this code works when I uncomment it and comment out StormSubmitter
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster(); 
        cluster.submitTopology("twitterTopology", config, builder.createTopology()); 
        Thread.sleep(70000); 
        cluster.killTopology("twitterTopology");; 
        cluster.shutdown(); 
        */ 
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("twitterTopology", config, builder.createTopology()); 

        Thread.sleep(70000); 

     } 

}
```

Any insight as to why it works in local mode but not in storm cluster mode would be appreciated!!

Comment: Are all necessary dependcies given in the `/lib`-directory?

Comment: In Intellij, I see Maven: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13 and 
Maven: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13 under External Libraries. This works when I run in local mode (the LocalCluster code above), just not when I run with my storm cluster.

Comment: Are these jars in the lib-folder of your remote storm installation?

Comment: When I open the bookmarks under External Libraries, I do see a .jar file. However, I don't see the actual .jar files in my IdeaProjects directory. Are you thinking I need to download the .jar files separately and link them in?

Comment: Your suggestion made me think I could download httpcore-4.4.10.jar and httpclient-4.5.6.jar, so I did. Unfortunately, I have been trying for the last four hours to figure out how to pull these jar files in to the Maven build in Intellij so I can create a package for my storm cluster, but w/o any success...

Comment: I give up for today. I was able to find the original httpclient and httpcore jar files and backed out the additions I had made. I can run Maven clean and package, a new jar file is created, but I still get the same error.

Comment: So you are referring to the distributed mode which then needs to run on a remote server and not on your local machine, right? In that case, Storm needs to access all the packages you use. One way is to either pack a uber-jar (e.g. with maven), another way would be to upload the additional packages to the lib-folder of your remote storm installation.

Comment: Thanks, moosehead42. When I select Package, Maven creates a jar file. How would I create the "uber-jar" you are suggesting?

Comment: So I preferred to solve it with the single jars that you need to upload just once. Uber-jar is an alternative that however inherently uploads all the packed jars every time. But is maybe easier to handle. Maybe read this as starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar

Comment: Really appreciate the guidance. I was able to use the details in the link to get it working. For anyone else who follows this thread, make sure to add back in <scope>provided</scope> at the end of the storm-core dependency so you don't get the duplicate yaml error. Thanks again, moosehead42.