# dependency not included in artifact maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a project multimodule, every module is defined as a jar, and every module, has some dependency like:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>it.demker.rapdev.be.esb</groupId>
            <artifactId>CR_RAPDEV_BE_PRODO_DEBICLIENT_V1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

As you can see there is no:

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

So after

> mvn clean compile package

If I open the jar file produced, i'm going to find the jar CR_RAPDEV_BE_PRODO_DEBICLIENT_V1
but there isn't any jar file, (inside my jar)?

How is that possible? For what I know if I don't specify provided, maven should be put the dependency inside the jar file.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, maven will not generate a jar with jars in it. Unless you have a plugin that does that for you, but by default this doesn't happen.

Comment: but if it was a war, I will have jar inside the war! if not put <scope>provided</scope>; where is written on maven doc that ....

Comment: Correct but war is something different from a simple jar. A war has a defined structure and libraries should go in `/WEB-INF/lib` this is what the `maven-war-plugin` takes care of.

Comment: If the project is building sucessfully, there must be something that excludes the artifact. Try to call mvn with -X flag to debug

Comment: @codigocaballer Building is not the same as running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, if you don't specify `provided`, maven will not put the jar dependency in a jar file.

By the way, the default **Java** ClassLoader doesn't support to load a jar in jar.
See [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) :

> **Note:** The `Class-Path` header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over Internet protocols. To load classes in JAR files within a JAR file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those classes. For example, if `MyJar.jar` contains another JAR file called `MyUtils.jar`, you cannot use the `Class-Path` header in `MyJar.jar`'s manifest to load classes in `MyUtils.jar` into the class path.

If you want to have all dependency in your jar, a solution could be to use maven [Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin to create [Uber Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11947093/5088764).

Answer (score 1):

JARs do not contain their dependencies unless you explicitly use something like Maven Assembly Plugin or Maven Shade Plugin.

WARs always contain their dependencies if they are not `provided` or otherwise excluded.